# WebRTC and Google Chrome App - microphone volume adjustment

Tags: webrtc, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to adjust microphone volume in Chrome App. Is is possible to do it? I'm using webrtc.

Answer (score 5):

It's possible

- to use WebAudio and a gain filter to adjust the volume
- to set the volume of an audio/video tag (on the receiving end)

Here is some sample code for the first option

```
var audioContext = new AudioContext();
var sourceStream = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(yourStream);
var gain = audioContext.createGain();
sourceStream.connect(gain);
gain.value = 0.9;
gain.connect(audioContext.destination);
```

and then use `audioContext.createMediaStreamDestination().stream`. `yourStream` is the original stream that you got from `getUserMedia()`.

Comment: Hi ;) I used second option to change speakers volumne but how can I do this for microphone? Or can you give me an example for first option?

Comment: I updated my answer. But I'll go for the second option. You cannot set the hardware options that you can set by right clicking on the speaker tray icon, selecting the microphone and then adjusting its level (supposing that you're in Windows).

Comment: Just note that the PeerConnection automatically controls volume, so using the answer above any dampening wil result in a higher HW microphone volume untill maximum is reached.